# Show GA stats of the website on the website itself

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We need to show the number of visits for pages of our website. We already use GA for general reports and we assumed that it might make sense to use GA API to get number of visits data from GA instead of building our own counters and increase load to our database and web server.

I read documentation and already know how to build queries that I need. The main problem I'm trying to work around right now is an authorization process. Sounds like if we use OAuth 2.0 each user has to authenticate before he/she can see the statistics on the page and they will have access to statistics of their websites (if they have them registered with GA). In our case this is incorrect, everything we need is just to show our own GA stats at our own website. Easy task as we thought initially but it doesn't sound like that anymore.

Is there a way to authorize our website to Google (like we send come credentials when we use Maps API) and show stats automatically to any user? We wanted to implement it on client side via JS but if this is possible to implement it on server-side only - that's OK. The target platform for server-side implementation is ASP.NET (just in case). Can someone point us in the right direction?

Comment: Please clarify: is there just one master google analytics account here?  Or does each of your "customers" have their own google analytics account and you are simply inserting their tracking code on their pages for them?

Comment: There is one master GA account, users/customers don't have their own. We simply want to use GA data in order to show statistics on the website.

Answer (score 3):

Quite a few options:

1. You can use [OOCharts](http://oocharts.org/) and a script like [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/29152)
2. Use a service like [embedded analytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/) (paid)
3. Use [SeeTheStats](http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/about?app_id=421002) and it's [widgets](http://www.seethestats.com/faq#c43)
4. Use [google charts and JavaScript](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/analytics/docs/articles/gdataAnalyticsCharts.html)
5. Use [explanium](http://explainum.com/) to embed a ga chart
6. [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) can [embed charts](http://piwik.org/docs/embed-piwik-report/) too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Google Charts looks to be a good approach but it seems if you want to load the data you still need to authorize each user via oAuth. Is there a way to send GA requests to my OWN data somehow else so each page can make it automatically without user interaction?

Other approaches require third-party service dependency, we don't want to have it if it's possible to get data from Google directly.